What does the absence of a ground state physically mean?
What does it physically mean, if a model in quantum mechanics or in quantum field theory has no ground state?
So I am talking about a Hamiltonian $H$ such that $\sigma(H)$ is bounded from below. So what is the physical difference, if $H$ has an eigenstate at the bottom of the spectrum, compared to no eigenstate existing at the bottom of the spectrum?
I am asking this because many authors in mathematical quantum theory care about proving the existence of a ground state for a given model, but I don't understand why that is so important.
The only answer i can come up with by myself is the following. If the lower bound $E_g$ is an eigenvalue with eigenvector $\psi_g(0,x)$, we know according the Schrödinger equation that the system once being in the state $\psi_g(0,x)$ at a later point it will be in the state $\psi_g(t,x)=e^{-iE_gt}\psi(0,x)$. Thus up to a complex phase, it will remain in that state.
However if the lower bound of the spectrum $E_g$ is no eigenvalue, we might measure the system at energy $E_g$ but it does not have to remain in this state. In this sense it is kind of unstable.

I'd assume that a lack of a ground state would imply an "infinite decay chain" of sorts, where the state continuously drops in energy levels since there is no last state it can reach.

I guess the key question is can these types of spectral features be stable in the presence of perturbations? I.e. can I couple this system to an environment it can decay into without changing the spectrum in a way that introduces a ground state

This reminds me at least in spirit of infrared divergences that arise in quantum field theory from processes that emit arbitrarily low energy massless photons. Essentially for a photon, $E=pc=h\nu$, where $p$ is the momentum, $\nu$ the frequency, $h$ Planck's constant, $c$ the speed of light. No exactly zero energy photons exist but you can get arbitrarily close.

There is still a ground state there (0 photons) because you have to allow processes that change particle number, but the existence of soft photons makes the analysis tricky.

I don't think you can measure a state to be at an energy that's not an eigenstate. At least theoretically? Measuring the states energy will project it down to an energy eigenstate. I don't really see a problem with many states asymptoting to a unreachable liwer bound in theory, but such a system will never be stationary. This may or may not be a problem depending on what you are trying to model.

@Fictional you can use a spectral measure, to calculate the probability that the system has an energy in an arbitrary small neighbourhood of the lowest energy.

Hi Mac Menders, Consider to limit the question to QM rather than QFT to keep the system as simple  and rigorous as possible.

@Qmechanic i don't do that for a purpose. As Andrew suggested it has to do something with IR-Problems in QFT. And the articles i am referring to in my post, they typically prove existence of groundstates for field-particle models. So Models in which a fixed number of QM-Particles interact with Quantum fields, like the Spin-Boson model or non-rel.-QED.

@MacMenders The idea with the photon case is that you have an infinite number of states with arbitrarily low energy, and in QFT you have to account for processes that produce superpositions of states that include very low energy photons. In the end it is mostly a technical annoyance but it is a subtle step that comes up. However as Qmechanic says, QFT is definitely going to be more complicated than quantum mechanics, I just brought it up since it had a similar flavor to what you are saying.

@Andrew i am interested in the QFT case, because this is what i am actually studying at the moment. Can you give any references (as mathematically rigorous as possible)? Because i still don't see how this is idea of infinite photons is connected with existence or absence of ground states.

You mean like a excimer is only bound in excited state?

Very interesting question.  I don't believe there is any principle prohibiting a scenario where there is no ground state, but the Hamiltonian is bounded from below.  It's just that for most systems there is a ground state, and showing the existence of the ground state is the easiest way to prove that the Hamiltonian is bounded from below, and also provides a nice way to build up all of the other states via operating on that ground state.

i don't think, proving the existence of a ground state is just there for proving the lower bound of the spectrum, because there are different and much easier techniques to show that the spectrum is lower bounded.

The free particle Hamiltonian has spectrum $\sigma(H_0) = [0,\infty)$, but $0$ is not an eigenvalue. More generally, any system that possesses only scattering states (For example $H = H_0+ V$ where $V$ is a positive bump or otherwise has some monotone falloff) will have positive spectrum with no bound states. In that sense there isn't anything particularly wrong with such systems. However, having a ground state has important implications for the dynamics of a theory, its phase structure, etc. For that reason it is useful for both qualitative and quantitative analysis of a model to understand whether or not it possesses such a state, and if it does, whether or not it is unique.
To elaborate on the point about dynamics, a theorem to look into is the RAGE theorem. Roughly speaking it states that for Schrödinger operators, a state that belongs to the continuous spectrum is 'scattering' in the sense that mass escapes any ball after sufficiently large time. On the other hand, eigenvectors are 'bound' , meaning their mass remains mostly localized in a bounded region. So if a system lacks any eigenstate, then it means that any and all states become delocalized given enough time.

What do you mean by phase structure?

How are you defining the spectrum? Not by eigenvalues of H? Or did you simply mean to write $(0,\infty)$ and the closed domain is a typo?

@Kvothe no its not a typo. The spectrum is always closed! Just look for the defintion of spectra of unbounded operators. The spectrum is in general much richer, than the set of eigenvalues.

@Mac, Hmm, it seems you are right that the usual definition in the case of  continuous spectra does give a closed interval (see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/662687/spectrum-of-unbounded-operators-spectral-theorem). Although I have yet to get some intuition for why such a definition makes sense.

@Kvothe the main reason why this definitions makes sense is that you can formulate with it the spectral theorem (which is the mathematical heart of Quantum Theory) even for ubounded self-adjoint operators with continuous spectra and at the same time it reduces to the set of eigenvalues for compact operators (like for example matrices).

@MacMenders That comment was referring to an interesting problem in many-body physics. There are many variations of the idea, but roughly the goal is to describe all 'classes' of quantum mechanical many body systems that possess the same large scale behavior and can be deformed into each-other without leaving the class. For example with topological insulators, one of these macroscopic properties is 'gappedness', which corresponds basically to the property of being an insulator.  If the gap closes along a path of models, the energy cost for an electron to hop into the conduction band vanishes.

@Kvothe I should note that 0 is not special here. $H_0$ has no eigenvalues at all. Here both Mac and I use the strict definition of an eigenvector, which requires that it is an eigenvector in a literal sense- It comes from a genuine (i.e. normalizable) eigenvector belonging to the Hilbert space.

I am not aware of any example where a Hamiltonian would be bounded from below but do not have a ground state.
On the other hand, one can easily come up with Hamiltonians not bounded from below and therefore not having a ground state. E.g., a particle in an electric field:
$$
H=\frac{p^2}{2m} - eEx
$$
In this case one would be typically interested not in the properties of the ground state, but in a flux generated  by the electric field (in presence of interactions with, e.g., phonons, it can be stationary.)
Another example is the inverted parabolic potential, sometimes used to study tunneling problems:
$$
H = \frac{p^2}{2m}-\frac{m\omega^2x^2}{2}.
$$
Scattering solutions can be found for this potential in terms of parabolic cylinder functions.

for an example, where the Hamiltonian is bounded from below, but has no groundstate, just take a free particle H=p^2/2m.

@MacMenders For a free, non-relativistic particle, $E=0$ is part of the spectrum -- in position space, you would just have a constant wavefunction, and in momentum space the wave function would be a delta function at $p=0$. However, a massless, relativistic particle, with $E=pc$ ($p$=momentum and $c$=speed of light) would be an example of what you're talking about, since there are no zero energy photons, but also no finite lower limit to the photon energy since they don't have a mass. But, particle number isn't conserved, and the vacuum is the ground state.

@Andrew +1 don't we get electrostatic field in the limit $k\rightarrow 0$? Another example is graphene with $E(k)=v|\mathbf{k}|$, though there we can also have holes with negative energies.

@RogerV. Although the "photons" in the electrostatic field are virtual and off shell.

@Andrew neither constant wavefunctions nor delta functions live in $L^2(R^d)$. So they dont't really exist in the Hilbert space.

@MacMenders Sure but they exist in the rigged Hilbert space which is what is actually used. Your argument would force us to throw out plane wave eigenfunctions, which would be very annoying. If it bothers you you can take a Gaussian around $0$ momentum as arbitrarily thin as you like.

Consider a Hamiltonian bounded from below. If there is no ground state, any state will not be the lowest energy state, which means that it could suffer a transition to a lower energy state. We can build a sequence of eigenstates with lower and lower energies, to see what happens near the bound.
If $B$ is the lower bound, for any given eigenstate associated to an energy $E_0$, there would be another eigenstate with energy $B < E_1 < E_0$ (otherwise, it would be the ground state). Following this construction, we can build a subsequence of Eigenvalues $E_0,E_1,...,E_k$ with associated eigenvectors and, for any number $N$, there will always be some eigenstate with energy
$$
| B - E_N | < \frac 1N
$$
which means that at some point, the eigenstates start to be more and more closer with each other in this sequence. Now, physically, we couldn't measure energy with arbitrarily precision, with means that at some point, we couldn't realize any experiment to differ $E_N$ from $B$. In this case, $B$ (or a very closer number), would be considered an approximate lower eigenvalue.
Now, the question is if the eigenstates $\Phi_k\rangle$ have the same property, i.e., if for $m,n>N$, we have
$$
|||\Phi_m\rangle - |\Phi_n\rangle ||^2 < f(N)
$$
For some bound $f(N)\rightarrow 0$ at large N. If this property doesn't hold, the system is transitioning between eigenstates with very similar energy, but very different states. It could be emerge as "degeneracy" of the "practical eigenvalue", some kind of degeneracy of the ground state.
If this property holds, for sufficient high $N$, we couldn't differentiate between different eigenstates, and we could say that the sequence converges for a non generate "practical ground state".

A bit more rigour
Actually, what we showed is that we can build a sequence of eigenvalues with associated eigenvectors $\{E_k\}$ that is decreasing by construction and bounded by below. So it is convergent. The question is if the associtated eigenvectors also converges. Now, it can happen that

The eigenvectors does not converge
The eigenvectors coverge in an unphysical state

If they don't converge, there's nothing we can conclude mathematically. The second is the best situation, because if it converge to an unphysical state, it would be at least arbitrarily close to physical ones. Now, for the first possibility, we could only say that there is a sufficient condition to not have it.

Eigenstates associated with arbitrarily close eigenvalues are arbitrarily close of each other

This assumption is highly assumed in perturbation theory, but I think it could not be proved for all systems. If it holds, we can say that the sequence of eigenvectors above always converge.

In conclusion, it seems that despite mathematically possible, a bounded Hamiltonian without ground state assumes arbitrary precision for measuring energies and to distinguish eigenstates, something that we couldn't achieve in practice. Any configuration like that would imply in a bounded sequence of eigenvalues and eigenvectors that, for sufficient high terms, we couldn't distinguish anymore and we could say that "converges" for some ground state

How do you know that there even exists a sequence of eigenvalues? This is not naturally given.

Is it not? I thought that Spectral theorem would guarantee the existence of eigenvalues. Well if that is not the case, consider that for Hamiltonians with a sequence of eigenvalues, my answer applies. Your question is about the physical meaning, not the mathematical necessary condition to have a ground state.

No, only for compact operators you have an eigenbasis. But almost all relevant operators in QM and QFT are not compact. In these cases the spectral theorem gives you a spectral measure instead.

This is likely not what you are looking for, but it is an important point nonetheless. Consider a free, non-relativistic particle in 1 dimension (or more). The Hamiltonian $H = - \nabla^2$ has spectrum $\sigma(H) = [0,\infty)$, but no ground state at $0$. Note that, in the infinite-dimensional case, $H$ need not have an eigenvector associated with each element of the spectrum.
More interesting is the case, which I think you are concerned with, where we have a sequence $\psi_j$ of energy eigenstates with energy $E_j \rightarrow E_{\mathrm{inf}}$ converging to the greatest lower bound of $\sigma(H)$, but for which $E_{\mathrm{inf}}$ is not itself an energy. Such a system should be constructable, in a rather silly way, using a infinite "comb" of square wells, each with depth slightly lower than the previous (but lower-bounded depth). You'll notice in this case that transitions are disallowed in a rather silly way. I cannot think of a more "interesting" example of such a sequence of bound states, but I have a feeling that any such examples will look rather contrived.
